# exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Wrong FS: abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folder, expected: hdfs://master-node:port

Tags: azure, apache-spark, cloudera

I am trying to execute a scala file using Spark Submit in CDP CDH 7.2.9 hosted on Azure Platform. But I am getting below error

`User class threw exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Wrong FS: abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folder, expected: hdfs://master-node:port at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:773)`

I have tried below options as suggested in stackoverflow but no luck !

a.`conf.spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS = “abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net”`

b.`val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(s"abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net"), spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)` in scala program.

c.`val adlsURI = s"abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net"     FileSystem.setDefaultUri = (spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration, new java.net.URI(adlsURI)) val hdfs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)`
in Scala program.

d.`conf.spark.yarn.access.hadoopFileSystems=abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net`

I am using Spark 2.4 version.

Comment: Have you tried editing the core-site.xml in the Spark conf folder?

Comment: yes, I have tried that option too but no luck !

Comment: Is the abfs filesystem jar (hadoop-azure) actually on your classpath? If you look at the docs, there's additional authentication settings you'll need, as well. Also, you should just be able to do something like `spark.read.format("...").path("abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/example/path")`